# How to strip shortcode in Wordpress HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom theme where when I upload an image with caption, the caption shortcode is shown on the page: `[caption id="attachment_109"]...`. Using either of WP's default themes, I see no issue. On inspection, WP uses `the_content()`, [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/), so I need to do some stripping. I get my posts with `get_page_by_path()`:

```
<?php

$post = get_page_by_path( $current_page->post_name, OBJECT, 'service' );

// I assume this would work
$content = the_content($post->post_content);

//Blank page:
echo $content;
```

Echoing `$post->post_content` shows the caption shortcode as mentioned above. How to get rid of if it? BTW, I need the caption values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the post content like this

```
$post = get_post(123);  //pass the id of the post
$content = $post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

or

```
$content=apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', 123)); //123 is the post id
```

after that just strip the shortcode also you can check if the post is having the shortcode in it or not by `has_shortcode`

Comment: Yup. All is well. Thank you!